# Is /etc/apt/sources.list supposed to change when doing do-release-upgrade?

Tags: 17.10, do-release-upgrade

On my Ubuntu 17.04 I recently started to get errors concerning missing packages when doing `sudo apt update`, which makes sense since 17.04 is no longer supported. So I replace the contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list with the following:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

And it worked OK. Later I upgraded it to 17.10, but the sources.list is still the same, it doesn't seem to cause any problems, but I sort of expected it to be filled with 17.10 repos after the upgrade.

Is this the way it is supposed to work?

Comment: artful is 17.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can there be any issue if I edit sources.list and jump between Ubuntu releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373514/can-there-be-any-issue-if-i-edit-sources-list-and-jump-between-ubuntu-releases)